# How to implement a scroll view on only part of my layout

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I want to create a layout that has 6 TextViews on the very top, 4 Buttons on the very bottom, and then have the entire center space be a scroll view with 22 Checkboxes ( 1 per line ). Basically I want a title bar on top, 2 buttons to navigate on the bottom, and a list I can scroll through in the middle.

I also would like the checkboxes to remain uncheckable, which I'm sure is a simple function call.

The view comes up with no upper title with text, and no lower bar with the buttons. Does anyone know what to do? The scrollview is the only thing appearing....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SN : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serialNumberView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ver : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versionView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Type : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/floatCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Float" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/tripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Trip" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/closeCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/blockedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Blocked" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/hardTripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hard Trip" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/phaseAngleCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase angle wrong for closing" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/diffVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Differential volts too low" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/networkVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Netwrok volts too low to close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Using Defaults( Reprogram )" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/relaxedCloseActiveCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Relaxed Close Active" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/commBoardDetectedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Comm Board Detected" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/antiPumpBlock"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Anti-Pump Block" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/motorCutoffCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Motor Cutoff Inhibit" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/phaseRotationCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase Rotation Wrong" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultDNPCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text= "Using Default DNP Profile" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Read" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You want a checkbox that isn't checkable? yet you use spinners...
I'd use a listview instead if I were you though. it should scroll within itself afaik.

Comment: I totally screwed this up sorry, I posted the wrong code, but I'd like to do a similar thing on both XML files, one has spinners and one has checkboxes

Comment: Edit it then. And still. Why do you want uncheckable checkboxes? use buttons instead?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't edited it yet because its literally the same problem, one just has a line of "TextView - Spinner" instead of "Checkboxes". And the reason for uncheckable boxes is because the User presses the Read button on the bottom, and it reads in data from another device and displays the current state of that device by checking some of the boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
LinearLayout
    LinearLayout
        Header-Elements
    /LinearLayout

    ScrollView
        LinearLayout
            Main-Elements
        /LinearLayout
    /ScrollView

    LinearLayout
        Bottom-Elements
    /LinearLayout
/LinearLayout
```

Remeber to use android:orientation="vertical" on the LinearLayout if you want that the elements apear beneath each other.

Comment: I assumed this is what I would need to do, but it is still not working... I will update my post

Comment: All that is showing up in my Graphical Layout is a centered TextView reading "SN:", other than that, it is empty

Comment: set android:orientation="vertical" in your LinearLayout, otherwise the first TextView fills the width, and the next textview will be next to it (outside the screen)

Comment: The bottom view of buttons is not appearing, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Set the height of the top and bottom LinearLayout to "wrap_content" and the ScrollView height to "fill_parent". If that doesn't work yet, try setting android:weight="1" on the top & bottom LinearLayout and on the ScrollView.

Comment: sorry? I think your keybaord gave out mid-sentence. I changed the LinearLayouts to wrap_content as well as the ScrollView to fill_parent, nothing yet

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, i'll re-post my code above

Comment: Haha sorry, I edited it to what you said, and then the guy who answered below suggested something else, so I changed it again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the pseudo layout design as per your requirement:

```
<LinearLayout
   ----
   android:weightSum="1.0" >

--- Your top elements ---

<ScrollView >
<LinearLayout
   ----
   android:layout_weight="1.0" >

--- Your scrollable items ----

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

--- Your bottom elements ---

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does layout_weight do to the view?

Comment: weight is assigning the whole space to your scrollable items fixing the top and bottom views. Your items will scroll within top and bottom and if you don't need this behaviour then remove weight.

Comment: This is what I want, but my bottom view of Buttons is not appearing. They are in their own LinearLayout, do I need to add a weight to them?

Comment: add android:layout_weight="1.0" in the linear layout inside scrollview  and remove android:weightSum="1.0" from the bottom linearlayout.

Comment: Sorry, but still nothing. I have updated the XML file above to what I now have. There is a warning on the layout_weight line iwthin the scrollView linear layout, which says " Invalid layout param in ScrollView: layout_weight"

Comment: put one linear layout outside scrollview with layout_weight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout for this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        // place your all the textViews here (all the top ones.)
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        // place your all scrollable views here.
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        // place your all the buttons here (the bottom part.)
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

As `RelativeLayout` places views *relatively*, by using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` the views can be placed on bottom part of the screen.

Comment: I have no idea why I downvoted this looking back at it now, sorry :/ If you go ahead and edit it i'll remove the downvote. Coming back to this question now that I know better, the obvious answer is to use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please remove the downvote. If you need any kind of help in understanding how exactly it works, feel free to ask. Now as you also agree that using RelativeLayout is an easier and correct way, you can accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

If some elements of the layout view is not showing, you can always use the  element to wrap the existing contents.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have a linear root view which houses three other independent children views. Setting the height of the scrollView to be fill_parent makes it take the size of the parent view, thus it prevent other children views who have a height of wrap_content from displaying.