# How to develop an UITableView with Section and ViewForHeaderInSection in Android?

Tags: android, uitableview

Good night, I'm new at this, the think that i need to do is  this effect using a sroll which conceal a title & displays the following. For example: what happens in the contact list, when you spend the A and B, but still keeps all contacts letter.

I have an example implemented in ios with ViewForHeaderInSection this is what they used to do this effect in instagram this is what I need to do in android.

This is the closest thing I found:

Visit [How to implement a scroll view on only part of my layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188353/how-to-implement-a-scroll-view-on-only-part-of-my-layout)

Thanks, I apologize for my English is not excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after search and search, i develop my woner layour with propierties...
This class help tu implements a #SlidePage into Fragment.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mijem.bitgray.us.mijem_android.R;

public class FragmentTutorial extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally
     * to access previous and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ImageView indicator0;
    ImageView indicator1;
    ImageView indicator2;

    List<ImageView> listIndicators = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_viewpager_tutorial, container, false);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                resetIndicators();
                listIndicators.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).setImageResource(
                        R.drawable.indicador_slide_on);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        indicator0 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator0);
        indicator1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator1);
        indicator2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator2);

        listIndicators.add(indicator0);
        listIndicators.add(indicator1);
        listIndicators.add(indicator2);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //TabListener.onResumeFragment(this);
    }

    public void resetIndicators() {
        for (ImageView img : listIndicators)
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.indicador_slide_off);

    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects,
     * in sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            fragment.setPosition(position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}

    enter code here
```

and the adapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            fragment.setPosition(position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

enter code here
```

Code of fragmen pattern

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mijem.bitgray.us.mijem_android.R;

public class FragmentTutorial extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally
     * to access previous and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ImageView indicator0;
    ImageView indicator1;
    ImageView indicator2;

    List<ImageView> listIndicators = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_viewpager_tutorial, container, false);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                resetIndicators();
                listIndicators.get(mPager.getCurrentItem()).setImageResource(
                        R.drawable.indicador_slide_on);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        indicator0 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator0);
        indicator1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator1);
        indicator2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.indicator2);

        listIndicators.add(indicator0);
        listIndicators.add(indicator1);
        listIndicators.add(indicator2);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //TabListener.onResumeFragment(this);
    }

    public void resetIndicators() {
        for (ImageView img : listIndicators)
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.indicador_slide_off);

    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects,
     * in sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            fragment.setPosition(position);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```